# DOM structure, get element by attribute name/value

Tags: php, dom, curl, getelementsbytagname

I see a lot of answers on SO that pertain to the question but either there are slight differences that I couldn't overcome or maybe i just couldn't repeat the processes shown.

What I am trying to accomplish is to use CURL to get the HTML from a Google+ business page, iterate over the HTML and for each review of the business scrape the reviews HTML for display on that businesses non google+ webpage.

Every review shares this parent div structure:

```
<div class="ZWa nAa" guidedhelpid="userreviews"> .....
```

Thus i am trying to do a foreach loop based on finding and grabbing the div and innerhtml for each div with attribute: guidehelpid="userreviews"

I am succesfully getting the HTML back via CURL and can parse it when targeting a standard TAG name like "a" or if it had an ID, but iterating over the HTML using the PHP default parser when looking for a attribute name is problematic:

How can I take this successful code below and make it work like intended as shown in the second code which of course is wrong?

**WORKING CODE** (Finds,gets, echo's all "a" tags in $output)

```
$url = "https://plus.google.com/+Mcgowansac/about";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$output = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$DOM = new DOMDocument;
@$DOM->loadHTML($output);


foreach($DOM->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
        # Show the <a href>
        echo $link->getAttribute('href');
        echo "<br />";}
```

**THEORETICALLY NEEDED CODE:** (Find every review by custom attribute in HTML and echo them)

```
$url = "https://plus.google.com/+Mcgowansac/about";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$output = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$DOM = new DOMDocument;
@$DOM->loadHTML($output);


foreach($DOM->getElementsByTagName('div[guidehelpid=userreviews]') as $review) {
        echo $review;
        echo "<br />"; }
```

Any help i correcting this would be appreciated. I would prefer not to use "simple_html_dom" if I can accomplish this without it.

Comment: Rather than you getElementsByTagName('div[guidehelpid=userreviews]') can't you just stick all the divs in a big array and iterate over them  ( roll your own solution ?) - or you could use one of the various XQUERY type classes out there ( that's what you pseudo code's trying to do right ?)

Comment: Well, sticking every DIV in the page response into an array and then iterating over the array seems like it would greatly increase the script load. Maybe im wrong but seems to be really inefficient. I'll try it though and see how it works out.

Comment: yes you're right it would add a lot of server CPU / Server load - I've not looked recently but if there were a native ( e.g. compiled C ) XQUERY library that'd be ideal as it'd be nice and fast and efficient and you could do exactly the sort of query you're trying to do there

Comment: It's quite likely that you wouldn't be able to extract all the information you want without executing the Javascript on the page. I haven't looked to confirm in this case, but a lot of Google's pages rely heavily on Javascript for creating the content on the page. [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) might be a good way to go here. If this is not required, you will want to use [XPath](http://php.net/domxpath) to locate the target elements - I can provide help with this if desired (although probably not for ~9hrs)

Comment: @DaveRandom Thank you and after having success with the answer provide by Ghost I am left with data that is badly formed and not consistent since most of the produced code doesn't have DIV IDs. Basically your right, the information returned is far to difficult to get back to a displayable condition, so im going to give up on this approach. Shame though, nobody else seems to try this and it would be great script to develop,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest and you could use an `DOMXpath` in this case too. Example:

```
$url = "https://plus.google.com/+Mcgowansac/about";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$output = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($output);
libxml_clear_errors();
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$review = $xpath->query('//div[@guidedhelpid="userreviews"]');

if($review->length > 0) { // if it exists
    echo $review->item(0)->nodeValue;
    // echoes
    // John DeRemer reviewed 3 months ago Last fall, we had a major issue with mold which required major ... and so on
}
```

Comment: Ghost that looks promising, i'm done for the night but will try it in morning.Thanks for suggestion and example.

Comment: Thanks again, I'm going to accept the answer because it did in fact return the results. But the data returned is a horror job to parse it into individual "reviews" and make it CSS addressable for display since nothing has ID's and the CSS classes are not shared at a parent level. Guess i'm just going to abandon this particular approach and try something new. Thanks!

Comment: @DMSJax this is an area where PhantomJS (linked above) could really help you out. Because it is a headless browser, it will allow you to extract the computed styles etc from the acquired elements - it's not just limited to DOM manipulation in the same way the the PHP DOM extension is.

Comment: @DaveRandom i glanced through it briefly last night but have not returned to it today. Once I get clear of some project stuff for the day i'll look more closely at it this afternoon and see if its an option. Thanks for the suggestion again.